# Can't upload file attachments to phpBB3 forum on IIS

Tags: file-upload, upload, iis-8, phpbb3

With reference to this thread (where, to be honest, I'm a bit lost with the technicalities):

https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=556&t=2520341&e=1&view=unread#unread

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I am unable to upload file attachments to my forum?

I've tried every solution I can find via Google, fiddled endlessly with permissions etc. on the webserver - I just can't get it to work, nor can i find any useful error messages anywhere.

I'd be great to finally fix this.

Comment: If I attach an image less than ~5KB, it works, anything larger it stalls.

My attachment settings say the max file size it 1MiB. PHP on the server is configured to allow 64MB.

Is there an IIS file size limit somewhere I don't know about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plupload hangs with no feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57796744/plupload-hangs-with-no-feedback)